# Wordpress blog page does not use css

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have set up simple wordpress page. Simple gallery, few forms and that's it. I decided to set up a simple blog page so I created a new page in `wordpress` and in reading settings I made it to be a posts page.

Now the problem is that this page does not use any styles. This is how it looks at the moment: https://nsjtomaszowlub.pl/galeria/aktualnosci/ . For refference here is regular page on this website: http://nsjtomaszowlub.pl/galeria/kalendarz-inicjatyw-duszpasterskich-2023/ .

I have checked in Wordpress template hierarchy that it should inherit everything from `index.php` and actually it does contain `html` from `index.php` file, however without `css`. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) . See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of the issue

Comment: _"and actually it does contain html from index.php file"_ - not sure what exactly you are referring to there, but the source code of  https://nsjtomaszowlub.pl/galeria/aktualnosci/ _starts with_ `<div class="frame_1">`- it does not contain even the basic _structure_ of a proper HTML document - no html, head or body element. And therefor no stylesheet embedded anywhere either.

Comment: @CBroe This is the very question of this post. Why it does not have proper structure? Why this page does not inherit it from ```index.php``` like all the other pages?

Comment: How do you expect us to be able to answer that, when we know nothing about your system's specifics? Only looking at the _results_ via the two example URLs you gave us tells us very little, and anything else - i.e., mostly the relevant code - we don't have access to.

Answer (score 0):

I have created really simple template and it used to work with static pages only. The solution was to create `home.php` file which could be a copy of `page.php`. However in order to make it properly display blog posts I had to change the wordpress loop. Here is some refference to the wordpress loop: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).